# Dini derivatives and fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have been looking for some references concerning the fundamental theorem of calculus and Dini derivatives and I did not find it. I would like to know if given a locally Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then it is related to its Dini derivative by

\begin{equation*}
 f(t)=f(0)+\int_0^tD^+f(s)\,ds.
\end{equation*}

Does someone knows a reference on that?

Comment: This should be true if $D^+f(s)$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: See Theorem 9 here: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~thomson/HagoodThomsonMonthly2006.pdf

Comment: Thank you, actually it is true, provided that $f$ is continuous, its Dini derivative is finite and integrable at every point [Theorem 10].

Comment: Why do you have $\mathbb R^n$ as the domain here? The equation seems to be one-dimensional.

Comment: @127.0.9.6. my bad! It was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For locally Lipschitz functions (and more generally, for absolutely continuous functions) there is no need to invoke Dini derivative at all. The [Lebesgue form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions) of the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $f'$ exists almost everywhere, is integrable, and its integral recovers $f$.

The results in *[Recovering a Function from a Dini Derivative](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~thomson/HagoodThomsonMonthly2006.pdf)* by John W. Hagood and Brian S. Thomson (reference provided by [Philip Hoskins](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707935/din-derivatives-and-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus#comment1482253_707935)) can be useful if you do not have absolute continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me.