# Fundamental theorem of calculus applied to a continuous function differentiable except on a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, reference-request

Consider a function continuous $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is differentiable except on a set $S$ containing countably many points, and its derivative on $[0, \infty) \setminus S$ is given by $f'$ (say). Suppose $f' \leq g$, where $\int_0^\infty g$ makes sense. Can we define $\int_0^\infty f'$, and say that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) - f(0) = \int_0^\infty f'$? If not always, are there sufficient conditions on $f$ when we can do it?

Comment: You may be looking for [absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity)

Comment: A sufficient counter-example is $f(x) = 1$ for $x\in \mathbb N$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is differentiable everywhere except $\mathbb N$, a countable set, but $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) - f(0)$ does not exist so the statement cannot be true.

Comment: $f$ is to be continuous.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks. I missed that. I think a much better statement of the problem would be in terms of $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ (assuming $f$ differentiable at $a,b$) as then limits do not need to be considered.

Comment: @mrf Thanks a lot for your comment. I am still trying to digest the link you gave. Just to understand an easier model case: let's say we know additionally that the function $f'$, wherever it is defined, satisfies additionally $f'(x) \leq e^{-x}$, say. Then we could say that $f$ is Lipschitz, and hence absolutely continuous, which makes the fundamental theorem of calculus go through. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is Lipschitz everything is ok. See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707935/din-derivatives-and-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus) (In fact, even weaker assumptions than absolute continuity are enough, for example existence of Dini derivatives.)

Comment: @mrf Oh, nice! That settles the question, thanks!

Comment: I don't see what is "settled."    An assumption such as $f'(x)\leq e^{-x}$ doesn't give you a Lipschitz condition on $f$.  If you want to add in an explicit assumption that $f$ is locally Lipschitz it is true that that would help.  Why not then just assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable and has compact support?  There's a sufficient condition that makes it all work too.  (I don't like the problem since it isn't focussed well.)

Comment: @B.S.Thomson  You are right. However, in my particular case, I later on checked that the "function" $f'$, wherever it is defined, actually has $|f'(x)| \leq e^{-x}$. This makes it Lipschitz, right? I will work out the line of argument given in your answer.

Comment: Yes, much better ...  and the problem drops down to a much easier level.  Now you can prove $f$ is Lipschitz (but remember it still takes some work since we are not assuming that $f$ is everywhere differentiable).  Also that assumption gets you $f'$ integrable on $[0,\infty)$.  The problem as you originally stated it has some tricky bits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of the intent of the problem.  Sometimes one might set a problem for a graduate student just to see the reaction.  I've heard of graduate students,
asked on an oral for the value of the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1 x^2\,dx$, quite baffled.

For one part of the problem you would have known long ago that the condition $f'(x) \leq g(x)$ along with the existence of $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$ does not help to conclude anything  about  $\int_0^\infty f'(x)\,dx$.  Take $g(t)=0$ and $f(t)=-t$ for all $t\geq 0$.  Usually we would have wanted something like $|f'(x) |\leq g(x)$.
Although you were asked this question in the setting of the Lebesgue integral, don't forget what you already know.

[Added note:  the poser of the problem uses the phrase "makes sense" instead of "exists."  So perhaps in this text infinite values are routinely allowed.  In that case consider the $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx=+\infty$ case separately and entertain the possibility that $\int_0^\infty f'(x)\,dx=-\infty$ when the former integral is finite.]

The other part of the problem is more sophisticated.  If $f$ is a continuous everywhere differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ (the countable exceptional set is irrelevant) $f'$ need not be Lebesgue integrable on $[0,T]$ and $f$ need not be absolutely continuous.  But then the condition that $f' \leq g $  for some Lebesgue integrable function $g$ comes to the rescue.

[Note added: if you are assuming only that $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx=+\infty$ then there is no reason to imagine that $f'$ is locally integrable.]

This is part of the theory of the Denjoy-Perron (aka Henstock-Kurzweil) integral.  If a DP integrable function on $[0,T]$ is dominated by a Lebesgue integrable function then that function is Lebesgue integrable.  Or one argues that the continuous differentiable function $f$ (or nearly everywhere differentiable function) is ACG$_*$ and then uses the inequality to show that $f$ is absolutely continuous.  Probably not in your course.

So really   your problem is just this:  *Suppose that $f$ is a continuous everywhere [or nearly everywhere] differentiable function
on an interval $[a,b]$ and that there is an absolutely continuous function $G$ for which $f' \leq G'$ a.e. Prove that $f$ is absolutely
continuous.*

Focus on that.

[I think the comments about Lipschitz functions and Dini derivatives don't really lead anywhere. The comment about absolute continuity is the key.]